# Which HTTP status code to return if credentials are correct but 2FA required?

Tags: rest, http, server

Pretty much just the title.

If a login request has a successful user identifier and password entered, but the system decided to issue a 2fa challenge to the user, what should the HTTP status code be?

Currently it's returning a 200 OK, and the data in the response indicates the 2fa challenge. This works functionally, but from a monitoring and alerting perspective there would be value in being able to more easily see in real time the number of requests with 2fa challenges. We do some DB logging on this that currently needs to be used for this purpose which is just more friction than I'd like.

I also have other use cases in mind that involves middleware services that it would be nice if they could see a 2fa challenge without needing as much intricate knowledge of the response format.

I looked through the list of 200-level response codes and none of them seem to fit, and I'd like to avoid using a 401 as we use 401 to indicate an incorrect password entry.

Answer (score 2):

Authentication really means that you are validating that the person in question is who they say they are.

If some operations require 2FA, in my mind what you're really saying is that you require stronger authentication.

`401` therefore feels the most appropriate to me if you are modelling an operation that failed due to the lack of 2FA authentication. If you 'want to avoid it', then you can use something like `400` or `403` as a fallback.

But if you are not modelling an error, but instead this is just a multi-step login process, and you are serving the form/action/json response that indicates that the next step in the process is the 2FA challenge, then the user is not 'at fault' doing this step, so 200 OK is the right choice.

If you need some other indicator in some part of your system, maybe don't overload the HTTP status code to mean a bunch of things they don't, and find some other way to communicate information.

Answer (score 0):

It should be a status code '403 Forbidden'. The user has provided correct login information, but they still don't and shouldn't have access to the resource because of the 2fa challenge, hence the 'Forbidden' status code.